# Css Auto complete for Select option

Tags: html, css, autocomplete

I am trying to achieve a auto complete function by Css  For Select Option so Beginner of web i could't it find any sample example for this.could some provide any idea or solution

For example::

```
  In a select box  by mention of class name like 

       <select id="productline" class="Auto-select on">
            <option value="Motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
            <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
            <option value="Ships">Ships</option>
            <option value="Trains">Trains</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: yes...CSS autocomplete

Answer (score 4):

Try this.
The `<datalist>` element specifies a list of pre-defined options for an `<input>` element.

The `<datalist>` element is used to provide an "autocomplete" feature on `<input>` elements. Users will see a drop-down list of pre-defined options as they input data.

Use the `<input>` element's list attribute to bind it together with a `<datalist>` element.

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FcLbz/)

Comment: fine it work perfect but in my requirement i need to add only by CSS class so is there way to achieve like by css

Comment: I don't think is there any way to achieve this only by css.

Comment: Or by javascript method like onkeyup,onkeydown

Comment: By only the select box id or name only auto complete have to achieve if possible provide some example

Comment: you have to search it out on the web. You can use jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/